# Как правильно сформулировать предложения, начинающиеся со "сколько"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Я иностранка и изучаю русский язык. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сказать:

- сколько нужно ехать домой?
- сколько времени нужно ехать домой?
- сколько по времени  нужно ехать домой?

---

- сколько идет урок по китайскому языку?
- сколько времени идет урок по китайскому языку?
- сколько по времени идет урок по китайскому языку?

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Добро пожаловать на наш сайт! Наверно, Вы в имени перепутали последнюю букву или просто опечатались. Не Лизв, а Лиза.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все эти варианты грамматически возможны, но стилистически они неравноценны.

> *Сколько* нужно ехать домой?

В этом вопросе не уточняется, о **времени** или о **расстоянии** хотят узнать (ожидается ответ по выбору собеседника).

> *Сколько времени* нужно ехать домой?

Это более конкретный вопрос.

> *Сколько по времени* нужно ехать домой?

Выражение "**по времени**" (с предлогом) - *уточняющее*. Оно оправдано в случае, когда вопрос "**сколько ехать**" был задан неопределённо (собеседнику неясно, *в каких величинах* оценивать) и нужный ответ не был получен, т. е. если хотят **переспросить** (в противном случае предлог *избыточен*). Например:

> -- Сколько ехать домой?
>
> -- Десять километров.
>
> -- Сколько (это) **по времени**?

Соответственно, в вопросе о длительности урока вариант "*сколько по времени*" вместо "*сколько времени*" менее обоснован. Из трёх вариантов вопроса в этом контексте естественнее *второй*. Но и его можно улучшить ("времени идёт" = длится):

> Сколько *длится* урок китайского (языка)?

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!! :)

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, первые варианты вполне подходят для ***разговорного*** стиля, вторые более *строгие* и, скорее всего, *обязательны* для ***официального*** стиля речи. Выражения *"сколько **по** времени"* мне кажутся избыточными, но могут быть хорошими для случаев, когда собеседники не понимают друг друга, чтобы разжевать, сделать до конца понятным вопрос:

> — Сколько нужно ехать домой?
>   — Сколько человек поедет?
>   — Нет. Сколько ***по времени*** нужно ехать домой?

Вопрос из первого блока можно сформулировать ещё по-другому, сделав его более прицельным, менее пассивным:

> *Сколько нужно времени, чтобы добраться до дому?*

*Нужно* тут можно заменить на *надо,* но тогда это будет характернее для разговорного стиля.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!!:)